# How do I install a new schema for OpenLDAP on Debian 5 with dynamic config=cn backend?

Tags: debian, openldap, debian-lenny

I'm importing an OpenLDAP database from another server and while importing, I got some errors with some users, the problem is that the `mozillaAbPersonAlpha` is not a valid `objectClass`.

```
#!ERROR [LDAP Error Code 21 - objectClass: value #3 invalid per syntax]
...
dn: uid=somedude,cn=Whatever,dc=test,dc=com
sn: Some Dude
givenName: Dude
mail: dude@test.com
mozillaCustom1: Engineering
l: Somewhere
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: mozillaAbPersonAlpha
uid: somedude
cn: Some Dude
```

AFAICT It seems that my installation of OpenLDAP is lacking a schema for [mozillaABPersonAlpha](https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Mozilla_LDAP_Address_Book_Schema).

But how do I install this schema?

---

EDIT: The server is using the new configuration backend, so there isn't any `slapd.conf` file. There is, instead, a `/etc/slapd.d/` directory with the weird directory naming (e.g. `/etc/slapd.d/cn=config/`).

How do I add the new schema in this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I wanted to know how to solve the problem while using the new `slapd.d/dynamic/cn=config` backend and I didn't wanted going back to the `slapd.conf` method. (Almost nobody is doing this, AFAICT)

When I try to add the new schema using `ldapadd, I was always getting the following error:

```
ldapadd -H ldap://whatever.test.com -D "cn=admin,dc=whatever,dc=test,dc=com" -x -W -f mozillaabpersonalpha.ldif
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
```

So the `BindDN` I was using does not have that privileges. I would need to setup an ACL or to use the `rootDN` for that operation.

I don't know why, but when configuring the `slapd` debian package, it allowed me to create an admin account for my on DIT, but it mentioned nothing about the `rootDN`. After some browsing, I found this [Blog](http://cloughnet.org/jeremy/networking/ldap/ldap-installation-and-configuration/) that explains how to set the password of the `rootDN` while using the `cn=config` schema.

So, edited the file `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase\=\{0\}config.ldif` and added the following:

```
olcRootDN: cn=admin,cn=config
olcRootPW: mypassword
```

I had to restart the slapd for the changes to take effect (It shouldn't be necessary, but ...). In order to test it, I ran the following command:

```
ldapwhoami -H ldap://whatever.test.com -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -x -w mypassword
```

And it worked! The next step was to load the `mozillaAbPersonAlpha` schema in ldif format using `ldapadd`:

```
ldapadd -H ldap://whatever.test.com -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -x -w mypassword -f mozillaabpersonalpha.ldif
```

The response was successful

```
adding new entry "cn=mozillaabpersonalpha,cn=schema,cn=config"
```

Finally, adding one user that depends on the `mozillaABPersonAlpha` schema is now possible. For example, the file `newuser.ldif` has this:

```
dn: uid=somedude,cn=Whatever,dc=test,dc=com
sn: Some Dude
givenName: Dude
mail: dude@test.com
mozillaCustom1: Engineering
l: Somewhere
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: mozillaAbPersonAlpha
uid: somedude
cn: Some Dude
```

And adding it to the new directory (not using the `rootDN` account) works now:

```
ldapadd -H ldap://whatever.test.com -D "cn=admin,dc=whatever,dc=test,dc=com" -x -W -f usertest.ldif 
Enter LDAP Password: 
adding new entry "uid=somedude,cn=SomeGroup,cn=whatever,dc=test,dc=com
```

Comment: Also applies to Centos 6.

Answer (score -1):

Copy 'n paste [that schema](https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews%3aMozilla_LDAP_Address_Book_Schema) into a file on your server, and add:

```
include /path/to/that/file.schema
```

in your slapd.conf and restart slapd.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wasn't very clear about the setup. I edited the question with the details.

Comment: Only works for ldif based backends: olc based use the {N} ordered config files and [require import since 2.4](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html#use-schemas).

Answer (score -1):

In your slapd.conf(5) file there there will be a (few?) "include" statements:

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
```

You need to download the schema file and put it in the schema/ directory with the rest of the ones already there (everything in one location is simpler), and change the configuration to include it. Then restart OpenLDAP.

http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/#include